# Get level index by using scene name in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I know that there is a way to get level name by index:

```
string levelName = Application.GetLevelNameByIndex(2);
```

But is there a way to identify the level index of a scene using its name?

Comment: What do you need this for? If we have a better understanding, of what you want to achieve, it may be easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that's not very well supported right now, see [this answer](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/137796/get-level-name-by-index-without-loading-it.html).

> Only in editor - as per this question.
>
> Vote for it here, it's a bizarrely absent feature.
>
> Note that if you want to show text to the user, you probably want a long name, a description, and a screenshot anyway.

EDIT: [Found an answer that has an editor script that may be of assistance.](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/33263/how-to-get-names-of-all-available-levels.html#)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method you could use, assuming you know how many scenes are in your game.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SceneDetector : MonoBehaviour {
    public int numberOfScenes = 5;
    public String[] sceneNames;

    void Start() {
        sceneNames = new String[numberOfScenes];
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfScenes; i++)
        {
            sceneNames[i] = Application.GetLevelNameByIndex(i);
        }
    }

    public int GetSceneIndex(String sceneName)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < sceneNames.length; i++)
        {
            if(sceneName == sceneNames[i])
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

And of course as you can see if you run `GetSceneIndex` and it returns -1, then the string you passed in is not a name of a scene.